# Unity texture images as embedded resource

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I am developing a Unity managed plugin. At the moment the dll works fine however when I want to use embedded resources, like images, the `Texture2D` does not load the bytes. Did anyone come across the same situation?

Here is my code to see if the images are really loaded to bytes and it works:

```
try
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.IO.Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("QBoard");
        img = ReadFully (myStream);
        print(img.Length);

    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error accessing resources!");
    }
```

However, when I want to load the image as following from the dll:

```
questionTexture.LoadImage(img);
GUI.Box (new Rect (dWidth/2-50, dHeight/2-50,200,50),new 
GUIContent(qlist.text,questionTexture));
```

The result is the following error at the test project in Unity editor:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. It was mistake with the variable initialization. Following code is working:

```
 try
{
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.IO.Stream myStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("QBoard");
        img = ReadFully (myStream);

    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error accessing resources!");
    }

    Texture2D myTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    myTexture.LoadImage(img);

    GUI.Box (new Rect (dWidth/2-50, dHeight/2-50,200,50),new GUIContent(myObject.text,myTexture));
```